# SQL Server Management Studio 2012/ALL Tools Install thru Command Line

Tags: sql-server-2012, sql-server-2012-datatools

Ok I managed to find the site, but I'm getting tired and upset so I figured if anyone knew a command line to just install tools thru the command line.  SSMS on the server is no longer allowing me to change Maintinance Plans, but it can run them just fine.

I've given up on resolving that issue after exhausting 3 hours worth of uninstall/reinstall/Register DLL/Blah/Blah/Blah.  Go to install the tools on my assistance computer and the idiot uninstalled Internet Explorer so now you can't launch SQL Install from the disk.

So if anyone happens to know the syntax I'd appreciate it very much, I just need the tools I don't need anything else.  SSDT/SSMS/ and the like.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms144259.aspx

Answer (score 5):

Try using

```
setup.exe /ACTION="Install" /IACCEPTSQLSERVERLICENSETERMS /Q /INDICATEPROGRESS /FEATURES="Tools"
```

Comment: Similar worked on SQL2008 R2 as well: SQLManagementStudio_x64_ENU.exe /ACTION="Install" /Q /INDICATEPROGRESS /FEATURES="Tools